# iOS Connect to a specific WIFI when opening my App

Tags: ios, wifi

I want to create an app wich displays certain content, but only if you are in a specific WPA secured wifi. For example the app is called AllianzArena Munich. If the person is in the AllianArena Wifi range and opens the app. The app should ask him: Wanna see content and connect to AllianA network or dont you?
If the User clicks yes he should be able to connect to the network with the correct WPA Code automatically (User doesnt see WPA Code but app does it for him)
I saw the CaptiveNetwork Reference, but didnt find anything about WPA Keys...

Is this even possible and does it make sense to investigate further?

Thanks in advance i hope you can help me
Peter

Comment: If this is going to be an Appstore app, then no this is not possible. Apple has not released any public API to achieve this.

Comment: Yes should be official... Isnt the CaptiveNetwork Reference kind of what I need? Or will it fail with the WPA part?

Comment: CaptiveNetwork will only work when the user selects to connect to the WiFi. Your app can not select the WiFi networks or even detect the WiFi networks that are available.

Comment: Thats to bad.But thanks for the answer anyway.